# Can't access public property on user control wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm trying to access a public property on a user control but I am getting this message. I don't think I would need to initialize the user control right? When I try to access the public property DirectorySetter.DirectoryPath I would get this message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'DirectorySetter.DirectoryPath'

Here is my user control code-behind:

```html
public partial class DirectorySetter : UserControl
    {
        public DirectorySetter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string DirectoryPath
        {
            get
            {
                return txtDirectoryPath.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                txtDirectoryPath.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the xaml that uses the user control:

```html
<Page
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoOrganizer.Pages"
      xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:PhotoOrganizer.UserControls" x:Class="PhotoOrganizer.Pages.PhotoDirectoryPath"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="PhotoDirectoryPath">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,91,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Set your photo directory path" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <UserControls:DirectorySetter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="btnSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any suggestion or help would be great!

Comment: Well the error message is very clear. Read some OOP basics about class and reference

Comment: If you want to reference that property from xmal it will need to be a Dependency Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the code where there error actually happens, where you try to access that "public property"

So I might just guess that you're trying to do something like

```
DirectorySetter.DirectoryPath = "asd";
```

which won't work since your class and your property aren't static.

What you can do though, is (xaml):

```
 <UserControls:DirectorySetter x:Name="myUserControl"/>
```

Code behind:

```
var s = (myUserControl as DirectorySetter).DirectoryPath ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your Property from `xaml` and or bind to it, you will need to implement a Dependency Property in your `UserControl` Class

```
// Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectoryPathProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "DirectoryPath", typeof(string),
     typeof(DirectorySetter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

// .NET Property wrapper
public string DirectoryPath
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DependencyProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(DependencyProperty , value); }
}
```

**Additional Resources from Msdn**

[Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)